# zoom in RecyclerView item with ScaleGesture

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, zooming

I have a Image View in every Item of RecyclerView an I want to Image View have zoom Option Like zoom In Gallery Application . I use the below code an its not work correctly.
this Scale gesture class is work correctly for sample view , but when i used this in RecyclerView it's not work correctly.
i search a lot and not found the perfect way to zoom in RecyclerView item.

```
public class SlideAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SlideAdapter.SlideViewHolder>{
private Context context;
private List<PageModel> pageList;

public SlideAdapter(Context context,List<PageModel> pageList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.pageList = pageList;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public SlideViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_book, parent, false);
    return new SlideViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SlideViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.onBind(pageList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()), holder.getAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return pageList.size();
}


class SlideViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      private ImageView imageView;
      private ScaleGestureDetector gestureDetector

    public SlideViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_book_recycler_view_slide);
        gestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,new ScaleListener(itemView));
    }

    void onBind(final PageModel page, int position) {
        Display.loadImage(imageView);

        itemView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {    
             if (scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
```

And this is my ScaleListener class :

```
public class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener  {

private View view;
private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;

public ScaleListener(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector){
    scaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
    scaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));
    view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
    view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi I am having similar requirement can you refer any resources to implement